# What is the most optimal way to work with the "names" variables?

Tags: python, preprocessing

Suppose the following `df`:

```
     Airplane_name   col2      col3     ...     colm
[1]     2352365236
[2]     6235231555
[3]     3463463435
        .
        .
        .
[n]     6497830120
```

Lets suppose that `n=10^6`.

What is the best way to work the `airplane_name` column?

One-hot encoding would cause too many columns. Should I leave that column as is, but convert it to a string?

Is it different for unique `int` values ​​than for unique `string` values? If the answer is "yes", what do you recommend?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can identifiers be used to train a model?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/92970/can-identifiers-be-used-to-train-a-model)

Comment: It gives me an intuitive idea of ​​how to solve the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: please, consider upvoting questions and answers that are useful to you.